# How to pass old value to setter if nothing is changed in computed property vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm learning to use Vuejs so don't mind me!

I have set getter and setter inside computed property and use it inside form with v-model. My problem is, if I change something inside the `v-text-field` then I can make `patch` request but if I don't change anything and leave it the value I got from the state then I can't make the patch request as it said the field may not be null.

How can I leave default value (value I get from state) to the `v-text-field` and be able to make patch request if i don't want to change anything inside the field.

my vue component.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="update-post">
    <v-dialog v-model="updatePostModal" max-width="600">
      <v-card class="px-5 py-5">
        <v-form ref="form" v-on:submit.prevent="update">
          <v-text-field
            type="text"
            v-model="title" <---
            label="Title"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1 white--text" @click="update">
            Update
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getAPI } from "../axios-base";

export default {
  name: "UpdatePostModal",
  data() {
    return {
      updateTitle: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    title: {
      get() {
        var title = this.$store.state.APIData.postTitle;
        return title;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.updateTitle = value;
      },
    },
  },
methods: {
    update: function() {
      var id = this.$store.state.APIData.postID;
      getAPI
        .patch(
          `/api/posts/${id}/`,
          {
            title: this.updateTitle,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`,
            },
          }
        )
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a few mistakes. First one, in here:

```
.patch(
  `/api/posts/${id}/`,
  {
    title: this.updateTitle,
  },
```

You are using the variable defined in `data` in your request. You should instead use the `computed` property so, it should be:

```
.patch(
  `/api/posts/${id}/`,
  {
    title: this.title,
  },
```

Next, the way you are using the state is also not right. If you are reading the `computed` property from the state you should always `set` it via the state as well. Otherwise, you'd end up with some unexpected behavior as your app grows. In order to do that you can do something like this:

```
get() {
    // read from the state
},
set(value) {
    // create an action to update the post title in the state

    store.dispatch(
        'updatePostTitle',
        value
    );
}
```

If you still don't want to do this, as a workaround you can address your problem like this (keeping in mind to fix the first issue mentioned above):

```
computed: {
    title: {
        get() {
            return this.updateTitle || this.$store.state.APIData.postTitle;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.updateTitle = value;
        },
    },
},
```